# Is it possible to weight paint across multiple meshes at once?

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have a project in which I need to be able to move facial structures in about 8 different head meshes. The faces are a bit low poly which makes them difficult to work with well, but with a lot of trial and error I can make them look alright.

Doing 8 of the exact same thing on items that aren't that different is frustrating though. I have tried transferring the weights from the completed mesh to the new one, but it doesn't work very well, and fixing it is sometimes more work than just starting from scratch. I would like to have all 8 or so heads in the same 3D space, and just paint them all at once if possible, or at least multiples at once if possible. Then I can go in and fine tune.

I should also mention that the biggest problem with these meshes is that there are a lot of duplicate vertexes, which cannot be cleanly removed with the "delete duplicate vertexes" option. Doing so tends to completely break the normals, UV map, or both.

Comment: Duplicate vertices may give you unwanted results. You will probably have to clean up most of the duplicates and UVs, recalculating normals should not be difficult.

Paint over multiple head would work out the same as transfering the weights, isn't it? What would be the difference? Why is this supposed to work better.     

Other than merging the objects, there is no way to weight paint multiple faces at once.

Comment: The meshes of the heads are different enough that transferring didn't work well. Cleaning up the UVs is tedious since it fragments and every individual face goes somewhere incorrect.

Comment: @ohgodzilla could you share your .blend file so we can help you?